# How to get React to wait for state to be set to render

Tags: reactjs

userAccess is a function from another component which returns an array that I am trying to turn into a state variable and display it in render, however unless I implement an onclick=findSubs, the render does not show the correct state variable values. I thought putting it in componentDidMount would do something but it did not

```
import {userAccess} from '../../firebase';

class MySubscriptions extends Component{
     
    constructor(props) {
        
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {subs:userAccess()};
        this.findSubs = this.findSubs.bind(this);
        
    }
    

    
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({subs:userAccess()});
               
    }

    findSubs(){
        this.setState({subs:userAccess()});
    }

    render(){
        return (
        
        <div>
            <Table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Subscription ID</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="body">
                {
                     
                   this.state.subs.map((aSub) => (
                    <tr key ={aSub}>
                        <td key ={aSub}>{aSub.id}</td>
                    </tr>))

                }
            </tbody>
            </Table>
            
        </div>
        
    )
}
}
export default MySubscriptions;
```

EDIT

This may not be the best way to do it, but it works

```
class MySubscriptions extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        this.state ={subs:userAccess(), loaded:false};
    }

    async componentDidMount(){

        await new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, 500); });
        this.setState({subs: await userAccess()}, () => {
            this.setState({loaded:true});
            return Promise.resolve();
        }); 
    }
    
    render(){  
  
        return (
        
        <div>
            <Navbars/>
            {this.state.loaded && 
            
             <Table>
             <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>Subscription ID</th>
               </tr>
             </thead>
            
             <tbody id="body">
             {
                 this.state.subs.map((aLine) => (
                     <tr>
                         <td>{aLine.id}</td>
                     </tr>
                 ))
              }
             </tbody>
        
            
             </Table>
            }
            
        </div>
        
    )
    }
}

export default MySubscriptions;
```

Comment: If you try to log the output of `userAccess()` in `componentDidMount` what will you receive?

Comment: @tomleb I receive the value I am looking for however the render does not refresh with the correct value

Comment: Strange. I don't see the problem with this. Is it possible to create a reproducible example? via [CodePen](https://codepen.io/), etc..

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) method.

In my opinion, the best practice is using the new Suspense component that was added with React 18, if you are using that version or higher.
You can read more about it and view code samples [here](https://17.reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html).

If you have an earlier version, you can also use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).